# How to set the value of the catalog's index SearchableText for an object

Tags: plone, zope

Is there a programmatic way in which I can set the value of the catalog index SearchableText for an specific object?

I'm using wsapi4plone to upload files to plone, but it has a bug (already reported) and it doesn't set catalog's SearchableText. I would like to be able to set it myself. I tried reindexObject() but it didn't worked.

Comment: What kind of objects are we talking about here? Archetypes, Dexterity, standard Plone content types?

Comment: Archetypes. I'm using Plone 4.2. The object uploaded are Files

Comment: And what type of files are you uploading?

Comment: PDF files. If I upload these files using plone interface, everithing goes well. But if I use wsapi4plone.post_object, SearchableText is empty. That's why I need a way to regenerate SearchableText *just for a particular object*.

Comment: If SearchableText doesn't work when wsapi4plone posts the file something more is wrong than just searchable text not working; a reindex should normally fix this.

Answer (score 1):

File object contents need to be transformable; the `portal_transforms` tool needs to be able to produce text from their binary contents.

For PDF files, for example, the `pdf_to_text` transform either uses the poppler or the xpdf command-line tools to extract text from the document to index. Word documents require the `wv` package, etc.

You need to make sure the right tools are installed for your platform for these transforms to work.

These older knowledgebase articles still apply to Plone 4:

- [Enable full-text indexing of Word documents and PDFs in Plone 3.0 (GNU/Linux)](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/enable-full-text-indexing-of-word-documents-and-pdfs-in-plone-3-0-gnu-linux)
- [Enable full-text indexing of Word documents and PDFs in Plone 3.0 (Windows)](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/enable-full-text-indexing-of-word-documents-and-pdfs-in-plone-3-0-windows)

Comment: Thanks. portal_transforms works fine. If I add a PDF file using plone interface everything is OK. The problem is when it's uploaded using wsapi4plone. So, I intercepted wsapi4plone.post_object. Now I need a way to reindex SearchableText in the recent created object. reindexObject() didn't work. Is there another way to set SearchableText?

Comment: But are you creating normal File content types? Sorry if is a stupi question, I don't know wsapi4plone.